How to test flow paging data for an android application?
I'm currently testing repository class in my Android App, the function itself returns Flow<PagingData>. When I run the test it gives an error :
After waiting for 1m, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: [ScopeCoroutine{Active}@5b397692]
override fun getPagingMovieFlow() = pager
            .flow
            .map { pager ->
                pager.map {
                    it.toMovie()
                }
            }

and I'm trying to compare it to mock data
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun getPagingMovieFlow_success() = runTest {
        val movies = movieRepo.getPagingMovieFlow().toList()
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(mockMovies.size, movies.size)
        assertEquals(mockMovies.map { it.toMovie() }, movies)
    }

How to resolve this issue?
All other tests are passed successfuly
I tried to get along with coroutines rule and used advanceUntilIdle()
Here is all MovieRepoImplTest:

class MovieRepoImplTest {

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineScope =  MainCoroutineRule()
    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val movieFactory = MovieFactory()

    private val mockMovies = listOf(
        movieFactory.createMovie(),
        movieFactory.createMovie(),
        movieFactory.createMovie(),
        movieFactory.createMovie()
    )

    private val mockMovieDetails = movieFactory.createDetailedMovie()

    private lateinit var fakeApi: FakeMovieApi
    private lateinit var movieRepo: MovieRepoImpl

    private lateinit var pagingSource: PagingSource<Int, MovieDto>

    private lateinit var pager : Pager<Int, MovieDto>

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        fakeApi = FakeMovieApi().apply {
            mockMovies.forEach { movie -> addMovie(movie) }
            addMovieById(mockMovieDetails)
        }

        pagingSource = FakeMoviePagingSource(mockMovies)

        pager = Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 20),
            pagingSourceFactory = {pagingSource}
        )

        movieRepo = MovieRepoImpl(fakeApi, pager)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun getPagingMovieFlow_success() = runTest {
        val movies = movieRepo.getPagingMovieFlow().toList()
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertEquals(mockMovies.size, movies.size)
        assertEquals(mockMovies.map { it.toMovie() }, movies)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun getPagingMovieFlow_error() = runTest {

        pagingSource = FakeMoviePagingSource(mockMovies, true)
        val pager = TestPager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20), pagingSource)

        val result = pager.refresh()

        assertTrue(result is PagingSource.LoadResult.Error)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun getMovieById_success() = runTest {
        val movieDetails = movieRepo.getMovieById(mockMovieDetails.id).first()
        assertEquals(mockMovieDetails.toMovieDetails(), movieDetails)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun getMovieById_error() = runTest {
        fakeApi.setReturnsError()

        try {
            movieRepo.getMovieById(mockMovieDetails.id).collect()
            fail("Expected an HttpException to be thrown")
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            // Expected exception
        }
    }
}



RepoImpl:
class MovieRepoImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val moviesApi: MoviesApi,
    private val pager: Pager<Int, MovieDto>
): MovieRepo {

    override fun getPagingMovieFlow() = pager
            .flow
            .map { pager ->
                pager.map {
                    it.toMovie()
                }
            }

    override fun getMovieById(movieId: Int) = flow {
        emit(moviesApi
            .getMovieById(movieId, BuildConfig.MOVIES_API_KEY)
            .toMovieDetails()
        )
    }
}


when i dont use functions like: toList() and collect() for getPagingMovieFlow() in test it doesn't cause this error
